# .idxmax equivalent for a specific flag?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to return the column header that occurs after last occurrence of a specific number (Flag) which may or may not exist in the row

For example

```
A     B     C     D   Flag
1     2     3     4       
Flag  1     2     3       
5     70    3     1        
Flag Flag   2     1
```

I would like to then fill the 'Flag' column to read:

```
A     B     C     D   Flag
1     2     3     4       
Flag  1     2     3   B    
5     70    3     1        
Flag Flag   2     1   C
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace` Flag to `np.nan` and using `first_valid_index`(PS: If you would like fill na with blank you can using `fillna('')`,I would like keep it.)

```
df1=df.replace({'Flag':np.nan})
df['Flag']=df1.apply(lambda x: x.first_valid_index(),axis=1)[df1.isnull().any(1)]
df
Out[211]: 
      A     B  C  D Flag
0     1     2  3  4  NaN
1  Flag     1  2  3    B
2     5    70  3  1  NaN
3  Flag  Flag  2  1    C
```

Comment: @wingsoficarus116 yw